# How can i call Snowflake stored procedure from Datastage ETL Tool

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have few snowflake stored procedure and i need to call them from Datastage tool?What is the procedure we can do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can call a Snowflake procedure by using CALL:

```
CALL myProcedure();
```

Docs: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/call.html

Regarding Datastage: You can send the CALL-statement the same way you send other SQL-queries to Snowflake.